# Tired in an enjoyable way

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a single word meaning "tired or fatigued in a good or enjoyable manner", as one would feel after a good day's work, or after some proper exercise. For example:

> After a strenuous gym session my body felt enjoyably tired.

I've considered *tired, fatigued,* and *worn out* but they all seem to have negative connotations.

Comment: *Enjoyably tired* is rather good.

Comment: We have pretty stringent requirements for [single word requests](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests) and I don't feel this question meets those requirements. The example is good, but what words have you tried that don't fit right and why? Also, why do you need a single word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you intend to use it, you might look at:

> **[languor](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/languor?q=languor)** (n.)
>   *tiredness or inactivity, especially when pleasurable*.

Answer (score 5):

The colloquial phrase is, "I'm tired -- but it's a *good* tired."

Answer (score 4):

I would dismiss **languor** as wrong in the context given. In my experience, backed by the lecture of several dictionary entries, it's a tiredness stemming from the **lack** of the activity. One can't be in a state of languor after "a good day's work, or after some proper exercise", this would be mutually exclusive.

Comment: It could be used when referring to the inertia or "laziness" following exercise, but certainly not during the exercise.

Comment: I take your point, Zecrates, but I see it differently. I can't conceive of a situation in which I would use "langour" to mean "laziness, as a result of physical activity" - it implies the exact opposite. It's a somewhat poetic word best employed to describe the continuous state of lethargy, the lack of activity. I wonder what others make of it.

Comment: Also, the example sentence provided by OP is looking for an adjective.

Answer (score 2):

*Exhausted*, *spent*, and *drained* could all be used in a positive context, although I don't think any of these terms necessarily have positive or negative connotations in and of themselves.  That is, one could always say, "*I felt great but I was exhausted*."

Then, there's always this term:

> **[runner's high](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/runner%27s%20high?fromAsk=true&o=100074)** (n.)
>   *a state of euphoria experienced during prolonged running or other forms of aerobic, sustained exercise, attributed to an increase of
>   endorphins in the blood*.

Comment: I'd say no to runner's high. That's something that happens during the exertion, and is (mostly) separate from how tired you are. OQ seems to be looking for that sort of pleasently drained feeling you get when the exertion is over.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Yup, I agree with you – it's no exact fit, which is why I prefaced with "there's always this term" (as opposed to something like, "here's the word you're looking for").  But at least it does have the usually-positive connotation, which answers half of the bill.

Answer (score 0):

Is the word you are thinking of "exerted"?

Answer (score 0):

Another few colloquial phrases are...

leg weary, bushed, shattered, footsore, weary, zonked, dead on one's feet, knackered

etc

Answer (score 0):

What about "Slap Happy?" I know it's not a single word but it's a phrase in the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=slap%20happy) which means "to be happy and tired at the same time"

> I'm so happy tired = I'm very happy and tired.

From the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=happy%20tired).

Comment: Just a word of caution: [Other dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=slaphappy&ls=a) seem to define the term quite differently, and in the U.S., it often means [drunk](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/slaphappy).

Answer (score 0):

I agree that, stylistically, "languor" doesn't work.
I've come to the conclusion that English doesn't really have a word that fits this bill.

How about the word combination "exquisitely exhausted"? I came up with this cute alliterative collocation on my own, but knowing the power of groups, I typed it into google and was happy to see thousands of results. Clearly I'm not the only one who likes how it sounds.

Here are some examples that clearly reflect the intended meaning:

> Those feelings of being exquisitely exhausted after hours of sliding down dinosaurs and whales have never left me.
>
> Into the basket he goes. And, unless he is exquisitely exhausted, Alfalfa whines or barks incessantly on his throne.

"You're exquisitely exhausted after a full day of hiking and paddling ..."

Comment: Not common enough to be called a collocation, Nathan, so not an answer on ELU which looks at more established usage. It would probably work on Writing.SE, which deals with good writing advice.